# Can the compromise library handle indefinite pronouns?

Tags: nlp-compromise

I need to eliminate pronouns in a script. 
I'm wondering if there is a built in identifier for indefinite pronouns?

Answer (score 2):

you can find and remove pronouns with this:

```
nlp(myScript).match('#Pronoun').remove()
```

but if you are looking for a specific list of words (like indefinite pronouns) you can do something like this:

```
nlp(myScript).match('(anybody|anyone|everything)').remove()
```